# Use Laravel Valet with CakePHP 3 returns 404 Not Found

Tags: php, cakephp-3.x, laravel-5.5, cakephp-3.4, laravel-valet

From the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/valet#introduction) it says that CakePHP 3 works out of the box with laravel valet, however, I am getting a `404 Not Found`, Is there something special I need to do other than `valet park`? Something along the lines of specifying the Valet Driver maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Work's For me***

```
valet park
valet link
valet open
```

If still getting 404 then valet not found your project **index.php** file

If you want to share your project globally

```
valet share
```